# ST-JS How to write to browser console

Tags: javascript, java

I'm new to [ST-JS](http://st-js.github.io/index.html), and I would like to output some debug info to the browser console.

I found `org.stjs.javascript.Console;` but can't make it work.

I tried this way:

```
Console console = new Console() {};
console.log("Hello");
```

But the I get an error like this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Console is not defined
```

Anybody knows how to use it like they do on the [ST-JS reference page](http://st-js.github.io/reference.html)?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a static import of `Global.console`:

```
import static org.stjs.javascript.Global.console;
```

Then you can log just as you would in Javascript:

```
console.log("Hello");
```

Another way, if you don't want to make the import static, is to use the a fully qualified log statement:

```
Global.console.log("Hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

simply try `console.log("hello")`. 
No need to create an instance of console

Answer (score 1):

just try this no need of the above code you have created

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

Comment: I just had to add `import static org.stjs.javascript.Global.console;` and it worked.

I think this is because I am using a namespace with the `@namespace` annotation.
Thanks